# Can Adsense/Bing Ads be used in Node Webkit desktop applications?

Tags: javascript, node.js, adsense, node-webkit

Title says it all. There is little documentation on this. Do not want to violate terms of service.

Comment: What are you talking about? Cannot understand

Answer (score 2):

According to the AdSense policy documentation, AdSense for content cannot be used in an application. Basically, if it's not in a webpage with a domain based URL, it's not to be used with that program. If you have an application written in Android, iOS or Microsoft Windows Mobile, there's an SDK from AdMob for ads in apps. That's your only choice with AdSense.